# How can I display an array of images inside a Modal in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-ios

I am using galleryswiper library to display an array of images inside a modal but when i navigate to the modal component and onPress the modal opens up i don't see any images. Can anyone help me how to pass the image sources inside the modal? Also i am unable to close the modal on Press of the icon.

```
export default class imagenav extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    state = {
      modalVisible: true,
    };
  }
  closeModal() {
    this.setState({modalVisible: false});
  }


render() {
  return (
      <Modal visible={this.modalVisible} onRequestClose={() => {} }> 
      <GallerySwiper
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "black" }}
          images={[
            {source: {uri: 

              dimensions: {width: 1080, height: 1920}}
          }

          ]}
      />
      <Header
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              borderBottomWidth: 0,
            }}
          > 
      <Right>
              <Icon
                name='close'
                color='white'
                onPress={() => {
                   this.setState({
                    modalVisible: false
                  })  
                  //this.closeModal()
                }}
              />
              </Right>
              </Header>

      </Modal>
  );
}
}
```

Comment: your source is empty, you need to require the images like this require("yourApp/image.png") or pass the URL to the image, and change the onPress props in <icon> to {() => this.closeModal()} you will need to change closeModal to arrow func or bind it to your contractor (depends on you babel config)

Comment: Yeah, here i didn't expose my source Uri. That shall be useful, thank you.